# Remove TextBox NoWrap Max Length

Tags: wpf, xaml

Is there a way to remove the `NoWrap` limit from a WPF `TextBox`?

---

Adding a very long string of text to a `TextBox` with `TextWrapping="NoWrap"` will still wrap after 9,600 characters.

**Windows Notepad** with `Word Wrap` off will still wrap after 1,024 characters.

**Sumblime Text Editor** does not seem to have a `NoWrap` limit.

---

Using a `RichTextBox` must still define a `PageWidth`.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1369184/6806643

This solution uses `MaxLines="1"`, except I need multiple lines for different sets of characters.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46322198/6806643

Comment: can't you use multiple textboxes with that last solution?

Comment: @Bijan With my project I need it all in one textbox, it can be hundreds of lines of text.

Comment: you could use an itemsControl bound to an observable collection containing separate lines of the text

Comment: @Bijan I `string.Join()` a large `List` and bind the `TextBox` to it. The amount of lines can vary each time depending on the items in the `List`.